# DomCrawler to get dateTime -attribute from <time>

Tags: php, domcrawler

The HTML

```
<time dateTime="2023-12-28T20:03:13.359+01:00">28 December 2023</time>
```

This works

```
$meta_description = $crawler->filter('meta[name="description"]')>attr('content');
```

This doesn't work

```
$published_at = $crawler->filter('time')->attr('dateTime');
```

This works (gives 28 December 2023)

```
$published_at = $crawler->filter('time')->text();
```

Comment: It might be the uppercase T in dateTime. Try camel case (date-time) or just 'datetime'

Comment: All lowercase letters worked! Thanks! :)

Comment: Yeah, part of programming is 'expect the unexpected'

Comment: @ezw Yes, that was a bit unexpected. Not even chat gpt could figure that one out.